# SQL Server, Inner Join involving multiple where statements

Tags: sql-server, join

I am having difficulties setting up the following query where I want to:

find all the WORKORDER values in the MATERIALSCOSTACT table that have one of two specific MATERIALID values.

Then from the WORKORDER table I want to weed out all the values with a 'main replace' or 'install' DESCRIPTION and then I want to make sure I am only looking at water or sewer ASSETGROUP. I want to make sure I am only looking at records that have a WOMACOST that have occured since the first of the year.

I would like to inner join the MATERIALSCOSTACT table and the WORKORDER table on their shared WORKORDERID column.

I cant figure out how to join the first statement with teh second, and in the second statement, SQL Server is giving me a syntax error on "INNER"

```
select workorderid from [CityWorks].[AZTECA].[materialcostact] where materialsid  = '30791' or 
materialsid = '30841' 


Select * from [CityWorks].[AZTECA].[WORKORDER] 
where description not like '%main replace%' and description not like '%install%'
and (assetgroup = 'WATER' or Assetgroup = 'SEWER') 
and womatcost != 0
and ACTUALSTARTDATE > '2013-12-31 00:00:00.000'
INNER JOIN workorderid on [CityWorks].[AZTECA].[materialcostact].[workorderid] =
[CityWorks].[AZTECA].[WORKORDER].[workorderid] 
group by assetgroup
```

Thank you very much to anyone who can help!

Comment: Thank you both! JiggsJedi your query worked perfectly

Answer (score 0):

You just have your where clause in the wrong place.  It needs to come after the joins.

```
Select * from [CityWorks].[AZTECA].[WORKORDER] 
INNER JOIN workorderid on [CityWorks].[AZTECA].[materialcostact].[workorderid] =
[CityWorks].[AZTECA].[WORKORDER].[workorderid] 
where description not like '%main replace%' and description not like '%install%'
and (assetgroup = 'WATER' or Assetgroup = 'SEWER') 
and womatcost != 0
and ACTUALSTARTDATE > '2013-12-31 00:00:00.000'
group by assetgroup
```

You may have to alias your tables or be more explicit in your where clause if those columns occur in more than one table.

Answer (score 0):

I believe this is what you want:

NB: try to use aliases, they make your code easier to read.

```
Select * 
from [CityWorks].[AZTECA].[WORKORDER] WO
JOIN [CityWorks].[AZTECA].[materialcostact] MC 
   on WO.[workorderid] = MC.[workorderid] 
   and (MC.materialsid = 30791 or MC.materialsid = 30841)
where description not like '%main replace%' and description not like '%install%'
and (assetgroup = 'WATER' or Assetgroup = 'SEWER') 
and womatcost != 0
and ACTUALSTARTDATE >= '2014-01-01'
```